# calculate difference between 2 lines

Tags: bash, awk, ksh

I'm writing this script in ksh / bash and need to print a title "Difference in count" when the output of the two lines are not equal.

The file name is test

```
fscsi0
fscsi0
fscsi0
fscsi0
fscsi1
fscsi1
fscsi1
```

Then:

```
cat test |awk '{b[$1]++}; END { for(a in b) printf("%25s %8d\n", a, b[a])}'
     fscsi0        4
     fscsi1        3
```

Comment: If you only ever have two "species/group by" result lines this should be trivial, or might there be some more lines and would then "any" difference among N lines trigger such an "alert" mesage. Please amend. Thanks.

Comment: There will only be two species/group by result lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping the OP's filter, why not simply stacking lots of small tools into a long pipeline? Here we go:

As there will always be only 2 evaluated groups to sum /count lines:

```
if [ "$(cat so_diff_line_grouped_sum.txt |awk '{b[$1]++}; END { for(a in b) printf("%25s %8d\n", a, b[a])}' | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 3 -d ' ' | uniq | wc -l | tr -d ' ')" -ne 1 ]; then printf "Difference in count\n"; fi
```

Should work. It yields with the input of so_diff_line_grouped_sum.txt:

```
fscsi0
fscsi0
fscsi0
fscsi0
fscsi1
fscsi1
fscsi1
```

The result:

```
Difference in count
```

Adding one entry fscsi1 to the file and rerunning it there is no output.

I use bash, have no ksh at hand ...

Broke down into multiple lines (for ease of reading):

```
linecount="$(cat so_diff_line_grouped_sum.txt |\
    awk '{b[$1]++}; END { for(a in b) printf("%25s %8d\n", a, b[a])}' |\
    tr -s ' ' | cut -f 3 -d ' ' | uniq | wc -l | tr -d ' ')"
if [ $linecount != 1 ]
    then printf "Difference in count\n"
fi
```

Picked up

1. OP's base formula,
2. squeezed all spaces adjacent spaces into single spaces via tr,
3. then used cut to pick field 3 (the count) of space separated columns (we left initial space before the fscsi* strings),
4. use uniq to evaluate if it is different per line,
5. count the lines with wc,
6. delete all spaces via tr and
7. compare this to 1

Comment: This is just plain stupid: `awk '... print "...."' | tr -s ' ' | cut -f 3 -d ' ' | uniq | wc -l | tr -d ' '`

Comment: Thank you @Dilettant for your answer.

Comment: @andlrc no, no, no - unix pipe lego land :-) I do not like awk, so it is often easier for me, to just solve with some stacking on top, compared to enhance the awk script "inside".

Comment: Also `!=` is for strings, use `-ne` for integers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you cannot change your existing program:

```
... | awk 'p && p != $2 { print "There is a difference!" }{p=$2}'
```

Comment: On my system the timing of the two solutions is comparable 15 vs. 17 milliseconds ;-) at least my suggestion compared to the one that one assembles from OP start of pipe line and your continuation (there has been an edit meanwhile in your answer).

Comment: @Dilettant I'm not talking about performance but maintainability.

Comment: But for a fast solution one can easily document like I did - no pressing reason to down vote my answer, but you mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

why not just...

```
awk '{a[$1]++} END{n=asort(a); if(a[1]!=a[n]) print "Different!"}'
```

can handle more than two blocks as well.